# Is this a real Chinese Proverb? (Pumpkins and Time Management)

Tags: proverb

Recently, I read this Chinese proverb. It looked amazing, but I wasn't able to find the Chinese version (or even find out if it actually existed).

"One cannot manage too many affairs: like pumpkins in the water, one pops up while you try to hold down the other.
- Chinese Proverb"

If you know how it translates, that would be a great help!

Comment: try 按下葫芦浮起瓢，e.g.feed to iciba
    释义

    hardly have one gourd been pushed under water when another bobs up; solve one problem only to find another cropping up; too busy to attend to all

Answer (score 3):

It's a real proverb and means what your quote says it means.

> [按下葫芦浮起瓢](https://zh.wiktionary.org/zh/%E6%8C%89%E4%B8%8B%E8%91%AB%E8%98%86%E6%B5%AE%E8%B5%B7%E7%93%A2)  (*àn xià hú lú fú qǐ piáo*)
>   variant: 按下葫芦又起瓢 (*... yòu qǐ piáo*)

葫芦 and 瓢 are two different words for *gourd*, similar to a pumpkin. These were used to collect water, so that's why you would want to hold them under water.

Answer (score 0):

It's also used to measure how good someone is with Kongfu - be able to handle or deal with multiple opponents at a time. 
手忙脚乱
应接不遐